# USB keyboard still doesn't work in Server installer

Tags: server, usb, keyboard

I've had a problem with the Ubuntu Server installer for a number of versions now. USB keyboards just don't work in it with USB Legacy enabled. I suspect it works with Legacy disabled, but I can't get that far since GRUB doesn't work with Legacy disabled so I can't get in to the installer.

Has anyone been able to work around this? It's not a problem with the keyboards or the computers. Multiple keyboards, multiple machines, multiple versions of Server installer all exhibit the same behavior. CentOS's installer works fine with Legacy enabled, so it's something specific to Ubuntu's Server installer.

Answer (score 0):

Lol i also use DELL USB Keyboard in ubuntu and it wors flawlessly
I think the first step to solving the problem would be listing the make and model of your laptop.
If it is hardware failure the only way I know would be to run:

Code:

`Memtest`

Comment: Well the trouble is there is no one USB keyboard, computer, or version of Ubuntu Server that I have this problem with. Every USB keyboard, every computer, every version of Ubuntu Server that I've tried. The only reason it's a big problem now is because I have a machine that I want to install on that doesn't have a PS/2 port that I can fall back to.